# how to check the value of a property in Ant

Tags: ant

I want to use Ant script to check if a property's value contains only [a-Z] and [0-9]? If not then exit with an error.

Is it possible to do that in Ant?

Comment: I notice you've only cast one vote on SO - please consider voting more often.  Voting up good answers encourages answer contributors.  Voting down any bad answers helps with the quality control of answers on the site.  You can vote on answers and questions, and on answers to questions other than those you posted yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check a property using the `condition` task, then use the `fail` task to exit.  Here's a = slightly modified - example from the [Ant manual](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/conditions.html).  Use a `matches` condition.  The regular expression will match any non-alpha, non-numeric character.

```
<condition property="nonalphanumeric">
  <matches pattern="[^A-Z0-9]" string="${property.to.test}" casesensitive="false"/>
</condition>
<fail message="String contains non-alpha non-number" if="nonalphanumeric"/>
```